# What does it mean when this error pops up when you are using Mule Web service Consumer connector ,"The SOAP request timed out"

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, connector

I configured the Consume connector in any point studio and when i try to run the project , This error pops up saying that "The SOAP request timed out". can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the proxy network? You have to set proxy if on the corporate network. That may be causing the timeout

else, set timeOut in HTTP Request connector and refer in WebService Consumer connection.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/migration-module-wsc

Comment: Thank you and ill try to figure it